# Oracle REST Data Services installed with Oracle APEX 5

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I just installed **Oracle APEX 5** under Oracle 11g, now, to be able to download reports as PDF, I installed the **Oracle REST Data Services 3.0**.

APEX is on port **8080**, and ORDS is on **8081**.
But now, it seems ORDS created a virtual new instance of APEX. In both ports I can use APEX (`localhost:8080/apex and localhost:8081/ords/`), but just in 8081 that the download as PDF is working.

Is this right?

This seems very strange to me. I followed the official oracle documentation. 
I would like to know if these products really works this way or if I did a mistake when installing and configuring.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle specialist, so any edits to improve my answer are
   very welcome.

**It seems that my installation is right.** According to the documentation:

> By default, the context root for accessing Oracle Application Express
>   through Oracle REST Data Services is **/ords**.

It's not clear to me the architecture of this product but, after reading the available docs, I interpreted that you have two ways to access APEX.

As I pasted right below, the documentation tells us that we need to turn off the APEX default port.

> If you were previously using the Embedded PL/SQL Gateway and now want
>   to use Oracle REST Data Services, you need to disable the Oracle XML
>   DB Protocol Server.

To do that, we need to disable HTTP port of APEX:

```
EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0);
```

This way, APEX will be acessible only by the [Oracle REST Data Services](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html).

Conclusion: this is an amazing product, but still lacks documentation, mainly on this architecture changes.

**Reference**

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/listener.htm#HTMIG29156
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/install.50/e39144/listener.htm#HTMIG29157